# Regular expression for comments in pascal

Tags: regex, pascal

I am implementing a compiler of pascal in Python. I need to find the regular expression for comments in Pascal. It should handle all these type of comments.

1) Single Line Comments  `//Comment1`

2) Multi-Line Comments `{Comment2}(*Comment3*)`

please give a regular expression that will handle all these 3 cases.

If this is difficult, give a regular expression which will handle `//Comment1` and `{Comment2}`

I want a single regular expression for all these three, if possible.

Comment: I have no knowledge about regular expressions. I just googled for comments in Pascal and did not find any regular expressions that will handle all these cases. So, I posted it here.

Comment: You're using regular expressions where you shouldn't. Consider learning about parsers.

Comment: @black_blood please accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: To reiterate what milleniumbug said, please read the specification and use a parser. Any solution here will not work in general case. If the string contains any of the sequence, then it will be incorrectly captured.

Comment: Depending on dialect nesting is also possible, so that is another nail on regex' coffin. As milleniumbug says, for parsing languages, use a proper parser.

Answer (score 4):

Comment 1:

```
//(.*?)
```

Comment 2 (compile with `re.DOTALL`):

```
\{(.*?)\}
```

Comment 3 (compile with `re.DOTALL`):

```
\(\*(.*?)\*\)
```

Then you can combine them all together in python code:

```
comments = []
comments.append(re.findall("//(.*?)", subject))
comments.append(re.findall(r"\{(.*?)\}", subject, flags=re.DOTALL))
comments.append(re.findall(r"\(\*(.*?)\*\)", subject, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

Comment: The `{}` need to be escaped as well

Comment: Is it not possible to find a single regular expression for all these three regular expressions?

Comment: @JanDvorak You're right. I forgot that python's regex is a but different.

Comment: @black_blood it is. Just combine them with alternation (`a|b|c|...`)

Comment: @JanDvorak: `{}` are not needed to be escaped.

Comment: For other regex flavors: If the multiline mode is not available, use `[\s\S]` intead of `.`

Comment: @Cylian `a{2,3}` is certainly something different than `a\{2,3\}`, in all regex flavors.

Comment: @black_blood why do you want a single regex after all?

Comment: @JanDvorak: It is certain for your example, but not for the answer of iTayb.

Comment: The correct flag is `DOTALL`, not `MULTILINE`, isn't it? `MULTILINE` only affects `^$`, if I understand correctly?

Comment: @Cylian so, _when_ don't `{}` need to be escaped?

Comment: @JanDvorak You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Single line comments:

```
//.*?$
```

Multiline 1:

```
\(\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*\)
```

Multiline 2:

```
\{(.|[\r\n])*?\}
```

Some Explanations:

`$` means end of line.

`.*` means 0 or more occurrence of any character, however it will eat your input string (depending on your regex engine settings, i.e., being single-line or multi-line). In order to make it less greedy, we have to use `.*?`.

The same is true about `(.|[\r\n])*?`. Here the `?` is more vital because if there are more than one closing braces, the innermost one is needed to be matched. Again depending on your regex engine options (single-line vs multi-line), the `[\r\n]` part may not be needed.

Answer (score -1):

Single line comments :

```
//.*
```

Multi-Line Comments **{Comment2}**

```
\{.*?\}
```

Multi-Line Comments **(*Comment3*)**

```
\(\*.*?\*\)
```

Comment: I guess that not everything in parentheses is a comment

Comment: The third one is wrong - you need to take care of the asterisks.

Comment: It's still wrong - the comment can contain a parenthesis or asterisk on its own.